# How to extend JointJs elements/links with typescript

Tags: typescript, jointjs

How to extend JointJs elements/links with typescript?

I've tried to use `this.set("defaults", obj)`, but it's ignored by jointjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JointJs has definition file for typescript: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jointjs

JointJs models are extended from Backbone, so it's possible to use `this.set(key, value)` expressions in constructor, except for "defaults" parameter, that needs to be written as method.

Example:

```
class MyType extends joint.shapes.basic.Rect {
  constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any) {
    super(attributes, options);
    this.set("markup", "<rect/>");
  }
  defaults(): Backbone.ObjectHash {
    return joint.util.deepSupplement({...}, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults);
  }
}
```

In subclasses of `MyType` it's possible to use `super.defaults()`:

```
defaults(): Backbone.ObjectHash {
    return joint.util.deepSupplement({...}, super.defaults())
}
```